# Win32_Volume Name doesn't match a mount point folder

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, wmi

We have a server with 20+ mount points.  All the mount points are physically working fine, however certain ones are showing a 'Name' of \?\Volume{GUID} in Win32_Volume.  In addition, in Disk Management, these same ones aren't showing a path when you right click on them and select Change Drive Letter and Paths.  But again, the MP is up and working.

Has anyone ever seen this before?  It's only an issue because I use a script to return all the MPs underneath a particular drive letter that uses Win32_Volume and it fails for this drive because they are listed as \?\Volume{GUID} instead of their path like all the others.

For anyone interested, here's the Powershell script:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class "Win32_Volume" -Filter "DriveType=3 AND (Name LIKE 'X:\\%')" | Select Name, Capacity, Freespace | ConvertTo-XML -As string'
```

Comment: A reboot resolved the issue, but I'm still not sure what the root cause was.

Answer (score 0):

They show up that way if they don't have a drive letter assigned. You could try searching for the label instead if it's the same for x:\ on all servers.

Comment: I have others without drive letters that don't show that way, they show the path to their mount point...